# sed: replace a space at specific position

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'd like to replace a space character in position 4 of `"abc "`, other characters at that position should be left untouched. Matching only for a space doesn't seem to work:

```
$ echo "abc " | sed "s/\ /d/4"
abc
```

Matching with `.` seems to do it, but it's matching too broad for my case:

```
$ echo "abc " | sed "s/./d/4"
abcd
```

Am I missing a detail about `sed`, or its regex flavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use range quantifier `\{min,max\}` or `\{num\}`.

```
$ echo "abc " | sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\) /\1d/'
abcd
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start. `\(..\)` called capturing groups. `.\{3\}` matches exactly three character, those three characters are captured by the group index 1. Later we could refer those captured characters by back-referencing.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to replace the 4th instance of space, which in this case it isn't. `echo "abc " | sed "s/ /d/"`

If there were at least 4 spaces in your text, it would work.

Edit: If you need to replace the 4th character you can do this: `echo "abc " | sed "s/./d/4"`

This means "replace the 4th instance of any character with d".

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the 4th part meant position, not match index.

Comment: is this `echo "abc " | sed "s/ /d/"` replaces the space at fourth position to `d` ? Is this works for all the cases?

Comment: see my answer. It replaces the fourth space with `d` . That is it only replaces the space  at the fourth position to `d`. It won't touch any other lines.

Comment: @purplehuman: I guess I could've been more clear. My use case is a log file that has lines like `" 9:43:12"`, and I wanted to add a "0" to prefix to the date for later sorting. While you identified my mistake, your suggestions aren't exactly what I need, so I can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it with `perl`:

```
echo "abc " | perl -pe 's/...\K /d/'
abcd
```

Ps. `\K` is positive look-behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace it then.

```
$ echo "abc " |sed -r 's/ /d/1'
```

The above command will search for the 1st occurrence of space character and replace it with `d`, for your case you can replace it with any thing you want.